# Getting 'undefined' .hexAccentColor value even when force fetching user?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to create an `info` command that pulls the specified users info. As per the discord.js docs, I'm force fetching the specified user to get the `.hexAccentColor`. The user I'm fetching does have an accent color, yet I get `undefined` as the value every time I try to get it. Here is my code:

```
const user = await client.users.fetch(
      interaction.options.getUser("user"),
      false,
      true
    );
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor(`${user.hexAccentColor}`)
      .setTitle(`User info for ${user.username}`)
      .addFields(
        { name: "User Tag:", value: `${user.tag}`, inline: true },
        { name: "User ID:", value: `${user.id}`, inline: true },
        { name: "Bot Status:", value: `${user.bot}`, inline: true },
        {
          name: "Account Creation Date:",
          value: `${user.createdAt}`,
          inline: false,
        }
      )
      .setImage(`${user.displayAvatarURL()}`);
```

All the other information is being passed correctly, it's just the color values that I'm getting `undefined` for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't actually force fetching. The arguments aren't correct (see [`UserManager#fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager?scrollTo=fetch)). Here's how to force fetch a user

```js
const user = await client.users.fetch(
    interaction.options.getUser("user"),
    {
      force: true
    }
)
```

But rather than fetching like this, you could do a simple [`User#fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=fetch), since `interaction.options.getUser` returns a `User` instance

```js
const user = await interaction.options.getUser("user").fetch(true)
```